# How to direct a user to a home page after logging out

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to modify a certain `php script` i bought as it has problems where users are redirected to `404 error page` after logging out. is there a way I can redirect them to my home page instead?

Here is the code im using to redirect after log out:

```
$data = ['status' => 200, 'header' => loadPage('header/content', ['site_search_bar' => loadPage('header/search-bar')])];
```

Iis there something im doing wrong?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. The above is just an array and two calls to a, for us unknown, function called `loadPage()`. We can't possibly know what's happening unless you show us more. When is that array created and how is it used?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for informing me. im not deep in php im a beginner , and this php file im editing is not something i created form scratch i just bought it online. may be i copy the whole code in the logout.php is that going to help in anyhow if no please suggest what i should do. thanks once again